# How to redirect stderr to stdout and to stderr itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, io-redirection

what I want to do is that redirect stderr to stdout without changing output of stderr.

say, `command` has output in stderr, I want to out put all in stderr to screen while also handle the infomation through grep and save it to a variable.

I tried

```
line=$(command 2>&1  | grep 'aaa' )
```

$line is passed with desired information but screen doesn't show any output.

I tried

```
line=$(command 2>&1 | tee >&2 |grep 'aaa' )
```

this can work fine for information output on screen ,but $line doesn't get any value.

Comment: why not add 'echo $line' after your first code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate stream using the redirection in the right order. Consider:

```
% cat out.sh
echo "OUT"
echo "ERR" 1>&2
```

Running:

```
% sh out.sh 1>&2 2>&1 | grep OUT > /tmp/a
ERR
OUT
% cat /tmp/a
OUT
```

Which seems to be what you're expecting. Now why does it works ?

- `1>&2` duplicates `stdout` to `stderr`
- `2>&1` duplicates `stderr` to `stdout`

So both stdout and stderr get the same stream.
Then stdout is greped.

Comment: You are only grepping stderr in this case though, whereas OP wants to output stderr and store stdin( i think).

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ I edited the post. I am grepping through stdout and stderr, after `sh out.sh 1>&2 2>&1 | grep ERR > /tmp/a`, `/tmp/a` contains ERR and after `sh out.sh 1>&2 2>&1 | grep OUT > /tmp/a`, `/tmp/a` contains OUT

Answer (score 0):

You can get fancy with some process substitutions:

```
$ sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2'
stdout
stderr

$ output=$( sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2' 2> >( tee >( cat >&2) ) )
# ...............................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
stderr

$ echo "$output"
stdout
stderr
```